# What are the types of authority required for the release of medical records?

Tags: united-states, privacy, medical

I am filling out medical records release in the United States. I noticed that the signature requires the patient's signature or a person authorized to sign. It also states that if not the patient, include type of authority to sign.

I only know of Power of Attorney as well as specific authority when unable to make medical decisions. What types of authority exist for release of medical records?

Comment: Are you asking about United States law?

Comment: United States Law

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parent can legally sign for a minor child. That is probably the most common situation. (In fact a child cannot sign for him- or herself.) A legal guardian can sign for his or her ward (person under guardianship). A person holding a **medical** Power of Attorney (MPOA) can sign for his or her principal. Other forms of authorization probably amount to alternate ways to create a MPOA.